# ViewFlipper crashes after orientation change

Tags: android, viewflipper

I'm trying to use inflate while using ViewFlipper to access to the data inside my view. I've done sample project that crashes.

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

**FlipViewBug.java**

```
package android.FlipViewBug;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
public class FlipViewBug extends Activity {

    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
}
```

When I rotate emulator from horizontal to vertical orientation <kbd>CTRL+F11</kbd> app crashes with ***stopped unexpectedly***.

If I remove line

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

app works fine. Am I trying to do something wrong? In my app I have more complex `LinnarView` that `ViewFlipper` is nested and the results are the same.

I was checking this on android 1.5, 2.2 and galaxy tab. There is no problem while rotating form vertical view to horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule of thumb if you're storing UI objectrefs in `static` data you're probably doing something wrong. :)  Even when things appear to work, you are likely to be leaking memory until Android decides to kill your process. See [Romain Guy's article](http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/) on this for more details.

So basically you answered your own question... don't do that! If you want to delay inflation of flipped-out views until they are flipped-in (i.e. as a performance improvement) I'd suggest you look into [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html).

Comment: Empty activity with ViewFlipper and no source code crashes after two screen orientation changes. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869153/application-crashes-after-screen-orientation-changed